# How to deploy WSO2 Stratos using Puppet

Tags: wso2, puppet

Does anyone know how to deploy WSO2 Stratos using Puppet?

It is better to have a more detailed tutorial.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no detailed tutorials available for deployment using Puppet. However the relevant puppet files are available at [WSO2 GitHub](https://github.com/wso2/Puppet/tree/master/Stratos) along with a README.

FYI: We recently [donated Stratos](http://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2013/06/what-the-you-just-gave-away-wso2-stratos/) to Apache Software Foundation and you can follow more details at [official web site](http://stratos.incubator.apache.org) and [mailing lists](http://stratos.incubator.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html)

There is no puppet deployment available for Apache Stratos (incubating) yet. The [architecture](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/Architecture) of Apache Stratos (incubating) is totally different when comparing with the initial version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand what you mean,There is no puppet deployment available for Apache Stratos (incubating) yet. 
Then I want to know how to deploy wso2 products such as AS, ESB, BPS using puppet?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no specific puppet scripts available to deploy WSO2 products. You can refer scripts at WSO2 GitHub for now. There are plans to create puppet scripts for deploying WSO2 products and those will be made public. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know when these puppet scripts for deploying WSO2 products will be opened and where can I get them?

Comment: I just know that DevOps guys have planned to work on puppet scripts for deploying WSO2 products. I guess it will take few months, may be end of this year. The team is busy with WSO2Con work http://us13.wso2con.com/ these days. And most probably those will be shared via the WSO2 GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can get puppet scripts/manifests for apache-stratos (inc. 3.0) via this link :

> https://github.com/wso2/private-paas/tree/master/puppet-scripts

It requires puppet 3.X and Ubuntu.